# Enable Properties, Security et al ZMI tabs in Plone 4

Tags: plone

Is there a way to re-enable the ZMI tabs for content -- like Properties (manage_propertiesForm) and Security (manage_access) -- which seem to be hidden by default in Plone 4? I know I can access them by URL, but it's difficult to remember the URLs for them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, using portal_action. There, you can add an action to the content types that point to manage_propertiesForm and manage_access.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure if I've explained myself clearly, however. Does this enable them in the Plone UI or the ZMI? I wanted to enable them in the ZMI but not Plone. I'll update my question if I've been unclear.

Comment: ops! for zmi you've to register them using manage_options. For example:

    manage_options = ( Folder.manage_options[:1]
                     + ({'label': 'Components',
                         'action': 'manage_components'},)
                     + ({'label': 'Components Folder',
                         'action': '++etc++site/manage_main'},)
                     + Folder.manage_options[1:]
                     )

in Products/CMFCore/PortalFolder.py

Comment: Looks fairly clear -- would this be something I'd put in setuphandlers.py or an __init__.py within my product?

Comment: just in your class code, look as other products do. For example RichDocument is a very good source of code to read :)